# error in database saving

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I am trying to create a form and save data to database when the submit button is clicked. But the data is not getting saved to database. i dont get any error. I am django 1.11. I referred to few stackoverflow question and that answers doesnt solve my issue. Could someone help in fixing it? Thanks in advance.

model.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class NameForm(models.Model):
    your_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.views import generic
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

from home.models import NameForm
from .forms import NameForm

class NameView(generic.View):
    model_class = NameForm
    initial = {'key': 'value'}
    template_name = 'home/name.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        model = self.model_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'model': NameForm})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = NameForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                return HttpResponseRedirect('thanks/')
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
                else:
                    form = NameForm()

                    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'home'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.NameView.as_view(), name='name'),
    url(r'^your-name/$', views.NameView.as_view(), name='name'),
    url(r'^your-name/thanks/$', views.NameView.as_view(), name='name'),
]
```

home/name.html

```
<form action="your-name/" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="your_name">Your name: </label>
    <input id="your_name" type="text" name="your_name" value="{{ current_name }}">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

forms.py

```
from .models import NameForm
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        model = NameForm
        fields = ['your_name']
```

Comment: You model and your form are named the same. So when you import them both in your view, only the last one (the form class) is being used.

Comment: You're not using a `forms.ModelForm`, so the `Meta` class does nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll get by much easier if you use the batteries included in Django. Here's a list of the fixes in the version below...

- Don't reuse names. `NameModel` is a model, `NameForm` is a form. (However, you'd usually really elide `Model` from a model name – it's just that `Name` sounded like a silly name for a model...)
- Use `ModelForm`s when you're managing models. They automatically validate input against your models, let you save the models easily, etc.
- Use the `CreateView`/`UpdateView`/`FormView` generic views to deal with model creation, updates, inputs, etc. No code needed, just configuration!
- Don't template forms yourself. `form.as_p` will get you a barebones form; `form.your_name` would render that field, etc.

Just a fair warning: this is dry-coded, so there might be typos or other small silliness.

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

class NameModel(models.Model):
    your_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NameModel
        fields = ['your_name']
```

## views.py

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import NameModel
from .forms import NameForm

class NameView(CreateView):
    model_class = NameModel
    form_class = NameForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('name-thanks')
    initial = {'your_name': 'value'}
    template_name = 'home/name.html'
```

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import FormView

from .views import NameView

app_name = 'home'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', NameView.as_view(), name='name'),
    url(r'^your-name/thanks/$', TemplateView.as_view({'template_name': 'home/thanks.html'}), name='name-thanks'),
]
```

## home/name.html

```
<form action="your-name/" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Comment: You've cranked it, found all issues in OP's question. Respect.

Answer (score 4):

That's beacuse you've been redirected (`return HttpResponseRedirect('thanks/')`) before save

Your version:

```
if form.is_valid():
    return HttpResponseRedirect('thanks/')
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            ...
```

And the version you seek, with redirect only after form saving and removed redundant second `form.is_valid()` check:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('thanks/')
else:
    ...
```

Comment: i do this i am getting this error `'NameForm' object has no attribute 'save'`

Comment: That's probably because you name your form and your model same name, which is a bad thing.

Comment: Sorry to ask. what should i change now? Name of my form or model?

Comment: Also take a look at @AKX comment, that you should inherit from `forms.ModelForm`.